# Is it possible to use Realm (in Swift) without subclassing Object?

Tags: ios, realm

I'd like to use Realm in Swift without subclassing Object; using Plain Old Swift Objects rather than Realm objects. The reason being I want to keep the Realm abstraction from leaking from my data layers into presentation.

Is this possible?

I could probably have a dedicated Realm object and then perform a mapping to a POSO but that shouldn't be necessary, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Realm, you *must* subclass Realm [`Object`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html). The [`Realm.add(_:update:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm3addFS0_FTCS_6Object6updateSb_T_) method requires an `Object` argument.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that by using [Unrealm](https://github.com/arturdev/Unrealm) library. Instead of inheriting from Object class you must just conform to the protocol `Realmable`. Even more, this enables you save value types (structs) as well!

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find some example of abstraction here:
https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/using-realm-with-value-types-b69947741e8b